# How could I create a sand dune animation?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation, smoke-simulation

I've been working on creating a whole bunch of nature animations and one that I've been trying to create is the "windy desert". Is there any way that I could simulate this in blender.

To be more clear, what I'm trying to create is something like the very start of this film on a sand dune
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYRu6MwmFYE

I don't care about my render times, I have plenty, I just want to know your ideas on how I could go about doing this.

Thanks :D

More Ref:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKkRF2sdXb8

[image]
https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-3wZZlRC5-1c/WCWs1H0EC9I/AAAAAAAAA5c/yTiXhJmQu4IF6F5-I7MpgMGy-j823mnqgCLcB/s1600/sand-dunes-in-windy-weather-loveoboi.jpg

[image]
https://theimaginativeconservative.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/desert-wind.jpg

[image]
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/RqrTvs9pmWk/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: are you talking about the sand blown by the wind or the dunes that dissolve? For the sand blown maybe particles following paths? There are some tutorials on this topic

Comment: Proportional editing maybe?

Comment: I just realized how horrible my description was, I am talking about the particle effect, of the sand blowing around

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to create realistic/physically accurate sand blowing over dunes animation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219614/how-to-create-realistic-physically-accurate-sand-blowing-over-dunes-animation)