# How to generate Reaction Diffusion animation?

Tags: node-editor, image, compositing-nodes

How to create Reaction Diffusion as animated texture (image sequence) in Blender?

[image]

Comment: For those who interested in what it is – [Reaction–diffusion systems on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction%E2%80%93diffusion_system)

Comment: You might be interested in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BD3HDVtsauI and / or https://iperson.github.io/tn_docs/ !

Comment: @Gorgious WOW ... what an awesome erosion ... thanks :)

Comment: @vklidu Yeah I'm keeping my eye on it, it's GPU accelerated and all, waiting until the UI and UX gets a bit more friendly :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since this site is meant to be as knowledge base … here is one option for *Compositor*. This technique mimics one used by image editor apps:

- Copy - Blur - Subtract - Contrast - Merge - Save … repeat with saved image

[image]
[image]

Add any your black&white image named like 0000.png from separate directory, because running rendering will generate an image sequence to that place.

The trick here is to reuse rendered and saved image for calculation of next frame. For that you have to add *Texture* node type **Image Sequence** even you have only your image for frame zero.
**Offset -1**  ... Thanks to [@Robin Betts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/219637/2214) for pointing that.

To speed up animation you can close nodes into a *Group* and use it a few times in line.

[image]

[image]

Additional post-pro (generated sequence with *Filter* node type *Sobel*, regenerated and used with Displays modifier).

[image]

---

There is also option use **Tissue** addon for 3D object … version bundled with official Blender release doesn’t contain Cache feature, to get animated version get latest version from [GitHub](https://github.com/alessandro-zomparelli/tissue)

Comment: Really cool, thanks for answering your own question :)

Comment: @JachymMichal Sorry for that ... I just did it a year ago in Ph with a script and lost it ... spend a time to restore from web infos ... here I can find it.

Comment: Hey man, I meant it sincerely. StackExchange [epxlicitly encourages users to anwer their own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20more%20than,own%20question%20at%20any%20time.) :)

Comment: OK ... thanks for the link :)

Comment: I think it's great to put up your own Q to be answered. I would have WOW!ed this earlier, but I've spent too long playing with it :D.. Hey! Who needs a camera?  Now I'm trying to work out what relation this has to  r-diff, as researched by Turing in his last days... A lot of the notation is beyond me, really.

Answer (score 1):

### Geometry Nodes - Simulation

a bit of update for the fun club here :) Since 3.6 simulation nodes are official ...

[image]

[image]

One of many in these days ... this one thanks to [Erindale](https://youtu.be/RSpkkuOOtBw).

[image]