# Dune Simulation

Tags: python, scripting, volumetrics, osl, height-map

Can [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YiAtM4EpQ4U&t=616s) be done in Blender? I tried subdivide plane and use python. But subdivision as excepted don't go well. Then I tried material volumes, but can't get desired resolution and can't see how program volume except osl. Then I tried, using subdivision modifier with displacement  modifier and script on texture image, but images in blender are stores as (r, b, g, a) when I only need [one](https://vimeo.com/234755478) and it takes much memory and processing time.

[image]

Comment: Check the answers [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/219614/35559) Somewhere, @vklidu demonstrated a more elegant version of my answer in another question, doing away with the camera, just feeding back through the compositor.. but I can't find it at the moment

Comment: @RobinBetts I don't want to disappoint you, but the only one thing I did with back feeding was [Reaction Diffusion](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/220499/2214) i never worked with sand in that way of your magic (•‿•) what is wrong with your solution ? It seems to match OP.

Comment: @vklidu Thanks! You could use your RD method (compositor only) on the dunes, too,  and get shot of the camera.. which does save a fair amout of faff. :)

Comment: @RobinBetts Can you share .blend file from [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/219637/141601). I would appreciate it very much if you could.

Comment: I've tried to put together a kit, with relative file-paths, [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aYE6Ze01AGnFkXrMehC-6xyK6bBeSl-x/view?usp=sharing). After extraction, before doing anything else, 'Render Animation'. That should populate the 'Render' folder with 25 demo frames and make everything else work. I hope :)

Comment: Thanks. Cool results.