# Is it possible capture the image result of a compositing and add directly, as a material, to a plane?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I made a simple compositing that I'd like to use directly as a material of a plane. I created a new material and in shading editor I put a texture coordinate node connected to a viewer node. In browse image to be linked of viewer node, I've chose Viewer Node. I connected the viewer node to a Princlipled BSDF in Base Color socket. In material preview I see the result of compositing, but the plane is showing an solid pink. What is it wrong? I'm using Blender 3.3.2.

Comment: Hello and welcome. It is recommended that you add some screenshots for better visualization and understanding of the issue at hand. Can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com.

Comment: Not directly, but if -1 frame is OK for you https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/220499/2214 or here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/224329/2214 ... btw How could you connect Viewer node to BSDF since Viewer node doesn't have output socket? +1 HarryMcKenzie

Comment: I made a mistake with the node label. Sorry, rectifying,  In fact I used a Texture Coordinate node with a Generated socket connected to the Vector of Image Texture node and, in browse image to be linked of this node I've chose Viewer Node. This node was connected to a Principled BSDF in Base Color socket.