# How can I create a Turing pattern shader?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

I'd like to create a [Turing pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_pattern) shader. Essentially [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/220498/how-to-generate-reaction-diffusion-animation) exact effect, but as a static shader for objects rather than a compositor animation. How can I do so? I've played with 4D Voronoi, Musgrave and Noise nodes but haven't been able to replicate it very well.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: The shipped [Tissue  Tools](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/tissue.html#reaction-diffusion)  add-on includes an implementation of reaction-diffusuion on vertex groups,which could be baked.  You could implement the simulation in the renderer, by feeding back through the compositor, in the same  way as @vklidu has done [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/220498/how-to-generate-reaction-diffusion-animation/220499) but the texture is still the result of a self-organising _process_ . I don't think there's an analytical solution for step N in that process.

Answer (score 2):

Turing patterns are usually produced in 3D using a reaction-diffusion simulation. As far as I know, this is the only way to obtain such a pattern. Erindale has a very recent tutorial for this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RSpkkuOOtBw