# Blowing sand / dust (I've tried the smoke method and it looks like smoke not dust)

Tags: particles

Evening everyone - I'm trying to get a simple sand / dust blowing across the scene and am a bit stumped. I've tried smoke and its too smoke like. I've tried particles with various force fields but it just looks wrong. I've notice a couple of animators use - what seems to be - video overlay??

Any thoughts would be appreciated. I'm working on a desert scene with wind blowing...

Andy

Comment: why didn't particles work? Video overlays seems to be a good idea but you need to find the videos

Comment: show us your particle try (blend file) and we pimp it up ;)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/219639/2214 ... or probably if you can attach some reference of desired result.

Comment: Thank you for the input guys - The animation I did (with smoke) would probably be too big to post here but it wasn't too bad but it looked like smoke blowing across the scene and not granular particles of sand. Particles are either to small to be seen or too big to be real. Apologies for the poor descriptions. I noticed there doesn't seem to be any Youtube videos suggesting how to do this (dust trail / cloud yes but blowing sand no) so maybe Blender is not suited to it?? I'll try and post the smoke results