# Text-in-sand effect in blender

Tags: animation, effects

How can a blowing-sand-revealing-text effect like this be achieved in blender?

[image]

(Due to limitations on file size, the GIF is of very low quality. A high quality version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYpV7.jpg)

I think this would need a LOT OF particles/objects...

Thank You.

Comment: I quess you need 1 object for floor, 1 object for text and fill it with a lot of particles with using of children to get even more and then you force fields to blow it. But I quess this will be very demanding for good HW

Comment: This tutorial shows a technique that will work: https://youtu.be/YFmN7eTNfNw

Comment: Here's a relevant tutorial: https://youtu.be/YFmN7eTNfNw

Comment: that video does not look like blowing sand at all....

Comment: To me, this looks like an animated displacement (Image Sequence created by Dynamic Paint) that reveals the text object and a smoke simulation on top. Something like this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/219614/107598